# Unsupported Data Source: ...Tennessee.tif.xml is not a supported raster data source

Tags: qgis, raster

I am new to QGIS, and when trying to load a raster file I get this error:

Unsupported Data Source: C:\Users\JAML\Desktop\TN_NLCD\NLCD2011_LC_Tennessee.tif.xml is not a supported raster data source

The raster is NLCD land cover data for the US, which I have used in ArcMap10 just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The file type is not a raster, it's an xml file associated with the raster.  The actual file you want to load will be named `C:\Users\JAML\Desktop\TN_NLCD\NLCD2011_LC_Tennessee.tif` (no .xml at the end).